# No layout defined for "StandaloneLayout" error while loading swagger ui through unpkg

Tags: swagger-ui

I am trying to use `unpkg` to load the swagger UI as mentioned in the documentaion [here](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/blob/master/docs/usage/installation.md#unpkg)

And when it loads it throws an error saying

```
No layout defined for "StandaloneLayout"
```

Anyone has any idea about this?

Comment: Looks like you already found an answer at https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/issues/4316. Would you mind adding the solution here for future visitors?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

For those looking for answers, here is the complete html that actually works

https://github.com/sunnyagarwal008/setup-swagger-ui-in-one-page/blob/master/swagger-ui.html

Comment: Thanks for the example. How did you create this example? Is this according to Swagger's spec? The official installation steps doesn't mention any of the code that you have presented: https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/blob/master/docs/usage/installation.md

Comment: The missing js files were added as per this link https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/issues/4316

Comment: This solution is not working anymore, if it ever did

Comment: It does work, just need to remove the line `layout: "StandaloneLayout"`